# Mutt not working due to "gnutls_handshake: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received." error

Tags: email, mutt

I am expecting lots of problem trying to make mutt work in Ubuntu 12.04. 
Here is my .muttrc : http://paste.ubuntu.com/1273585/

Here is the bug I am getting when i tried to connect.
`gnutls_handshake: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.`

Do anyone knows a workaround to fix this error.If so please suggest it asap.

Many Thanks in Advance!

For debug here is the output of my mutt -v: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1273590/

Comment: Are you on quantal?

Comment: No, Ubuntu 12.04!

Comment: I thought it was a 12.10 TLS issue that was fixed a couple days back, but I guess not, sorry.

Comment: I had the exact same issue today... And the answer on this page did not help. But the answer here : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66560/mutt-smtp-tls-error-sending-mail  solved my problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately this can be a problem with Mutt and its use of `gnutls`, as can be seen from the [Mutt mailing lists](http://marc.info/?l=mutt-users&w=2&r=1&s=tls_socket_read&q=b), however there are some solutions.

It is worth removing the header files from `.mutt/cache/headers` because they can sometimes cause problems.  I also note that in your `.muttrc` you do not have a `mailboxes` line. I use gmail in `Mutt` and have the following in my `.muttrc` (though yours may differ):

```
mailboxes +INBOX +archive +sent +drafts +spam +trash
```

I mention this because at [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnutls13/+bug/105736/comments/16) this error was discussed and someone mentioned that specifying only the correct mailboxes solved his problem.

Comparing your `.muttrc` to mine in general reveals no other differences, and `Mutt` and gmail are working for me with almost identical settings.

---

**However**, if these suggestions do not solve your problem, it is possible to build `Mutt` from source and ensure that you build it with `openssl` support, so you can use `openssl` instead of `gnutls`. I note that in your second Pastebin, your Mutt has indeed been built with `gnutls`, as your debug reveals:

```
-USE_SSL_OPENSSL  +USE_SSL_GNUTLS
```

Here `-` means without that attribute and `+` means with that attribute.

So, before we start building, purge the currently installed `mutt`:

```
sudo apt-get purge mutt
```

and then get the dependencies with

```
sudo apt-get build-dep mutt
```

It is fine to use `build-dep` here as the latest version of `mutt` (at this time of writing) doesn't require any newer libraries than those fetched with `build-dep`.

You will also need to make sure you enter:

```
sudo apt-get install openssl libsasl2-modules libssl-dev libssl1.0.0
```

Now download the latest source code from [the official site](http://www.mutt.org/download.html) (which is 1.5.21 at time of writing) and then verify the appropriate gpg signature, and 
`cd` to the downloaded file and unpack the source code with

```
tar xzvf mutt-1.5.21.tar.gz
```

Then pass these extra options to `configure` (we need to include the other options as well as `ssl` as `imap` and `smtp` support and other things are not compiled in by default):

```
./configure --enable-pop --enable-imap --enable-smtp --with-ssl --enable-hcache --with-gss --with-sasl --enable-debug --enable-gpgme
```

Then proceed to build and then install the program with

```
make 
sudo make install or sudo checkinstall
```

The build only takes a few moments and it should allow you to use `Mutt` again. It is probably a good idea to clear the header cache (as I detailed much further above) before you run the new program. It will use ssl automatically as there is now no tls support built in.

A screenshot from the newly compiled program (showing some older, non-personal emails):

[image]